# Force google spreadsheet to wait until cell calculation finish and then export to pdf

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script

In my google spreadsheet file I have many custom function, that perform requests to my server and download some data. I need to automatically export it to PDF and then send on particular email.

I wrote like this:

```
function sendPDF() {
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  var attach = {fileName:'MyPDF.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

  MailApp.sendEmail("example@email.com", "PDF test", "test", {attachments:[attach]});
}
```

And add trigger on time, that will execute this function every hour. The problem is, that with one spreadsheet I get PDF without downloaded data, and with another spreadsheet I get `We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 44, file "Code")` error.

How can I force google spreadsheet to wait until data will be downloaded and after download send me final PDF?

Comment: If this `sendPDF()` is independent of other functions and is called on it's own, then not really. you can try to do `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` that applies all pending edits, however, if the other functions have been called independently and have not finished (that is did not even provide any output) then this won't help. It's hard to say without any real code or example. The only thing you gave is the part that exports as pdf and sends e-mail which works as intended. The problem is elsewhere which we cannot see

Comment: @Vytautas The other code is nothing but bunch of methods, that download JSON from server via UrlFetchApp.fetch("myurl"). And I call them directly in cells.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, without the needed reputation I cannot comment above.

Why not having this as a separate function like you have now and just call the function in your main function that fetches the url and downloads the data.

You can even write the downloaded data on a separate spreadsheet and insert an IF function that when cells are not empty execute the pdf script! After executing the script clear() and loop if necessary.